# Charge in dielectric material

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to find a simple way to draw this but can't find a solution

[image]

Comment: What is your best solution so far?

Comment: Start with a single ellipse, figure out how to make the changes based on its x,y location, then add a bunch of them.

Comment: @Diana Where does the figure come from? a book?

Comment: yes it is from a textbook

Comment: @Diana What is the name of that textbook?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a solution following [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo)'s comment. I use a `\foreach` command to draw all the ellipses, but I rotate each one and change its minor axis according to its position.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{positive}{HTML}{FADDB9}
\definecolor{negative}{HTML}{7BC192}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\y in {-3,...,3} \foreach\x in {-4,...,4} % row, column
{%
  % atan2 implementation
  \ifnum\x = 0
    \ifnum\y > 0
      \def\a{90}
    \else
      \def\a{-90} 
    \fi
  \else\ifnum\x > 0
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{atan(\y/\x)}     % angle in quadrants  I and IV
  \else
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{atan(\y/\x)+180} % angle in quadrants II and III
  \fi\fi
  % dipoles
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\b{\x*\x+\y*\y}
  \ifnum\b > 0
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bb{0.08*sqrt(\b)} % semi-axis b = distance to the origin (scaled)
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},rotate=\a]
      \fill[positive] (0,\bb) arc (90:-90:0.4 and \bb);
      \fill[negative] (0,\bb) arc (90:270:0.4 and \bb);
      \draw (0,0) ellipse (0.4 and \bb);
      \node[transform shape,scale=0.6] at ( 0.2,0) {$+$};
      \node[transform shape,scale=0.6] at (-0.2,0) {$-$};
    \end{scope}
  \fi
}
% central charge
\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.15) node[scale=0.6] {$+$} node [red,below left] {$q$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
**Edit:** Two changes:

1. Following [Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano)'s suggestion I adapted the code for positive and negative charges. I added a parameter `q` that should takes values +1,-1 and that changes accordingly the x-axis. Then I needed an `\ifnum` for display the central charge.
2. `atan2`. Why not use the built-in function? You'll be thinking. Me too...

The new (and shortest) code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{positive}{HTML}{FADDB9}
\definecolor{negative}{HTML}{7BC192}

\def\q{-1} % central charge: +1,-1 we only need the sign

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\y in {-3,...,3} \foreach\x in {-4,...,4} % row, column
{%
  % dipoles
  \pgfmathsetmacro\a{atan2(\y,\x)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\b{\x*\x+\y*\y}
  \ifnum\b > 0
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bb{0.08*sqrt(\b)} % semi-axis b = distance to the origin (scaled)
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},rotate=\a,x=\q cm]
      \fill[positive] (0,\bb) arc (90:-90:0.4 and \bb);
      \fill[negative] (0,\bb) arc (90:270:0.4 and \bb);
      \draw (0,0) ellipse (0.4 and \bb);
      \node[transform shape,scale=0.6] at ( 0.2,0) {$+$};
      \node[transform shape,scale=0.6] at (-0.2,0) {$-$};
    \end{scope}
  \fi
}
% central charge
\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (0.15) node [red,below left] {$q$};
\ifnum\q = 1
  \node[scale=0.6] at (0,0) {$+$};
\else
  \node[scale=0.6] at (0,0) {$-$};
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the same picture with a negative central charge:
[image]

Comment: Very impressive code and design +1

Comment: Thanks, @SebGlav!!! ;-)

Comment: +1 surely. But if the charge is negative,like is it necessary to change the code? Inverting  the plus and minus symbols? \node[transform shape,scale=0.6] at ( 0.2,0) {$+$};
      \node[transform shape,scale=0.6] at (-0.2,0) {$-$};?

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano!!! Indeed, the code should be changed. I guess it could also be done with `\ifnum` or `\ifthenelse`, to take both cases into account but I think it's not worth it.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you got me thinking and I made an edit. Now the charge can have both signs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your acceptance of my request. Honestly, your drawing is veryyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

I simplify the code and calculations of @Juan Castano by creating a `pic` named `atom`, then putting `pic`s along paths (see option `[sloped]`, no `atan2` or angle calculation needed) from the origin to integer points inside a loop.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{pics/atom/.style args={major #1 minor #2}{code={%  
\fill[red] (0,#2) arc (90:-90:#1 and #2);
\fill[green!50] (0,#2) arc (90:270:#1 and #2);
\draw (0,0) ellipse(#1 and #2);
}}}

\def\atompath{(0,0)--(\x,\y) pic{atom=major .4 minor \bb} node[right,scale=.6]{$+$} node[left,scale=.6]{$-$}}
        
\foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
\foreach \y in {-3,...,3}
{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\b{\x*\x+\y*\y}
\ifnum \b>0    
\pgfmathsetmacro{\bb}{.08*sqrt(\b)}
\ifnum \x<0 
\path[nodes={sloped,pos=1,xscale=-1}] \atompath;
\else
\path[nodes={sloped,pos=1}] \atompath;
\fi 
\fi
}
    
% central charge
\draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle(.18) node[scale=0.6]{$+$} + (-135:.4) node[red]{$q$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, very good thinking!!

Comment: @JuanCastaño Thanks!

Comment: I associate myself with  @JuanCastaño +1.

Comment: My previous code gave wrong positions for `+` and `-` on the left part. Just fixed it!